# Set setter property

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

For a Windows 8.1 universal app, how can I set a Setter property on a click of a button? For instance, I would like to set the FontSize of the Key = "Mean" to something other than 28 when a user click a button:

```
<Style x:Key="Mean" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" TargetType="TextBlock">

        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28"/>
```

Any pointers?

Comment: have you tried getting a reference to the UiElement that is using that style and then changing its property value like: lvItem.FontSize = 50 ?

Comment: @Rafael: Yes, I tried that, but that does not change the setter property. What I am looking for is when I press the button, the value should be changed in <Setter Property = "FontSize" Value = "28"/>

Comment: I doubt that it is possible to do that. changing the setter property will not reflect on the items that use that style because you used 'StaticResource' when specifying the element. Now i am not sure of this, but you can replace it with a 'ThemeResource' and see if it works. I read somewhere that static resources are meant for the resources that will not change.

Comment: @Rafael: I doubt that what you are stating is wrong. AFAIK, Style BasedOn property must be a Style, not 'ThemeResourceExtension' object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by Victor here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/fcefee11-9758-43fa-80b2-02aa5a3ca9a0/set-setter-property-on-a-button-click?forum=wpdevelop

Adding the link for the benefits of the community.